# multiple image for same service

Tags: php, mysql

please help me to code image album with thumbnail.

if one user has different services and each service has multiple images.
example id user-1 has 2 services, service-1 and service-3. output willbe

output from query

1. service1 userid1 image1
2. service1 userid1 image2
3. service1 userid1 image3
4. service3 userid1 image1
5. service3 userid1 image2
6. service3 userid1 image3 etc.

using php code i need to display

1. service1 userid1 (image1,image2,image3) then
2. service3 userid1 (image1,image2,image3)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use GROUP_CONCAT() function like below

```
SELECT service,userid,GROUP_CONCAT(image)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY service,userid
```